# PATH being ignored when running Python in virtual environment

Tags: python, path, virtualenv, python-venv

I'm having an issue where my virtual environment is placing its /Scripts folder at the beginning of my **PATH**, but when executing "**python**" in the command prompt, I'm not actually executing the first python.exe that the path comes across.

My virtual environment *is activated* and my path does show the proper path to the venv's /Script folder.

```
C:\Users\me> b:
B:\> cd b:\my\venv\Scripts
B:\my\venv\Scripts> path
PATH=C:\Python36\Scripts;C:\Python36;C:\others\here
B:\my\venv\Scripts> activate
(venv) B:\my\venv\Scripts> cd B:\my\django\site
(venv) B:\my\django\site> path
PATH=B:\my\venv\Scripts;C:\Python36\Scripts;C:\Python36;C:\others\here
(venv) B:\my\django\site> python

Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 17:00:18) [MSC v.1900 64
bit (AMD64)] on win32 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license"
for more information.
>>>import sys
>>>print(sys.executable)
C:\Python36
```

Now, if I were to call **python** while I was still inside the venv's Scripts folder, it would have used the python executable in there. But once I leave, it seems to ignore the fact that the venv's Scripts folder is at the front of the PATH.

Perhaps I am misunderstanding how PATH works? My expectation was that the first python.exe that would be found in all of those paths, from left to right, would be the python.exe that is used. I'm having this thought now, as I type this:

Maybe PATH cannot handle multiple drives being referenced within it?

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated! Thanks, all!

Comment: `PATH` works differently on Windows to UNIX-like systems.  On Windows the search commences in the directory which is running the *calling program*, then the current directory, then the Windows directories, then `%PATH%`.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @cdarke This was informative, thank you so much.